# Filter elements from 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which represent stock prices over time and stock related information over time (e.g. fundamental data on the company).

Both dataframes contain monthly data, however they are over different time spans. One is 5 years, the other is 10 years. Also, both do not have the same number of stocks, there is only an 80% overlap.

Below is an example of the dataframes:

```
days1 = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1980', end='7/1/1980', freq='M')

df1   = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), columns=list('ABCD'),index=days1)

days2 = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1980', end='5/1/1980', freq='M')

df2   = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), columns=list('ABCDEF'),index=days2)
```

My goal is to reduce both dataframes to the inner joint. That is, so both cover the same time period and contain the same stocks. My index contains the dates, and the column names are the stock names.

I have tried multiple variations of `merge()` etc, but those recreate a merged dataframe, I want to keep both dataframes. I have also tried `isin()` but I am struggling with accessing the index of  each dataframe. For instance:

```
df3=df1[df1.isin(df2)].dropna()
```

Does someone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post examples of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the column intersection:

```
column_intersection = df1.columns & df2.columns
```

for the row intersection:

```
row_intersection = df1.index & df2.index
```

then just subset each dataframe:

```
df1 = df1.loc[row_intersection, column_intersection]
df2 = df2.loc[row_intersection, column_intersection]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is incredibly simple and beautiful, I spent a couple hours trying to figure this out!!